# Why drop macros as much as possible?

Tags: macros, clojure

What's the deal with not doing macros ? or what's the deal with trying to avoid macros ?

I've seen some posts recently telling to slow down on the use of macros: DSL!=macros, re-writing code with functions instead of macros, the begin of a study to switch from macros to functions...

but what's the deal ? you think macros will rule the world and you don't want that ?

What is wrong with macros? why lower their usage ? aren't they supposed to be a method to extend the language ?

Comment: As Steve Yegge put it: "Macros are like having these high-powered band-aids, when what you want is not to be wounded in the first place."

Comment: The point is not dropping them, but not overusing them.

Answer (score 11):

The main argument I see for preferring function to macros is that they aren't available as first class functions at run time, which limits your flexibility to use various powerful functional programming techniques.

Personally I think macros are still an extremely useful programming tool *providing you use them appropriately* - i.e. enabling you to do complex code transformations at compile time that would otherwise incur high runtime costs or require a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code.

Comment: And that's exactly the point: *use them appropriately*. No one tells you to avoid macros, but to avoid macros *as much as possible*.

Comment: +1 for "they aren't available as first class functions" because i didn't know that and that's really good reason to avoid them

Answer (score 3):

Christophe Grand's presentation at clojure-conj covered this well: http://vrac.cgrand.net/DSL.pdf

Hopefully the videos will be up soon.

Answer (score 0):

Drop macroes as much as possable:

- **without resorting to duplicating code**,
- repeating a pattern,
- writing unclear code,
- or as mikera points out, doing **significant** computation at runtime that could have been done at compile time.